# Pytest Parameterize From file Library -Is there any possible single Pytest script ,can pass multiple configuration files(.yml)

Tags: pytest

Pytest Parameterize From file Library Perfectly works for my requirement but I need to use multiple config files (.yml) for the same set of test conditions.

Example : test_stage.py (all the test conditions are present)

test_01_stage.yml
test_02_stage.yml
like wise multiple parameters file needs to be passed in same .py script

Please share the steps how to implement in pytest with help of Parameterize From file Library

I need to get single pytest script executed multiple config file(.YML) parallelly how to achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're asking about the [Parametrize From File](https://parametrize-from-file.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library?  If so, you can use the `path` argument (documented [here](https://parametrize-from-file.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/parametrize_from_file.parametrize.html#parametrize_from_file.parametrize)) to split your test parameters over multiple files:

```py
import parametrize_from_file as pff

@pff.parametrize(
        path=['test_01_stage.yml', 'test_02_stage.yml'],
)
def test_my_func(...):
    ...
```

If you want to run your tests in parallel, check out the [`xdist`](https://pytest-xdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) plugin.

Comment: Using your suggestion,I have tried multiple configuration values that were working fine, but I'd like to find a solution for the below approach from same parametrize_from_file library wihtout hardcode the config file path and name to dynamically pass the config file and execute the test conditions .Please share your suggestions 
test_stage.py ---> test_01_stage.yml ----> output 1 test_stage.py ----> test_02_stage.yml ----> output 2 . . . . test_stage.py ---->test_n_stage.yml ----> output n

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do.  Do you want to pass the name of the parameter file as a command-line argument to pytest?  If so, I don't know of any easy way to do that, but I suspect it would be possible to write a [`pytest_generate_test`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example) hook that does it.

Comment: Also, pytest_generate_test is not able to achieve for my usecase, but parametrize_from_file works perfectly. There is only one problem, which is the static path I need to pass. Parameterize_from_file fully covers the remaining 99% of my use case

Comment: any suggestion I would like to know in command line how to pass path to test function @parametrize_from_file (path ['runtime_user_input']